# Add formatting based on response - POST data sent to email using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

I have a form where people can fill in there details and share their current timetable. I then go and find the times that suit people and sort them into groups.

Currently the PHP form prints a variable either 'work' or 'free' (based on their selection in the form) into an table and then send a email with the contact details and timetable.

Is it possible to assign a text color or cell color value to that particular cell of the table, when sending the form?
(so that when I receive the email the cells that have the 'free' variable in them are colored green etc.)

```
  <?php

$name_f = $_POST['name_f'];
$name_l = $_POST['name_l'];
$phne = $_POST['phne'];
$cont_em = $_POST['cont_em'];

$MON09TO10H = $_POST['MON09TO10H'];
$TUE09TO10H = $_POST['TUE09TO10H'];
$WED09TO10H = $_POST['WED09TO10H'];

...


$to    = "email@email.com";
$subject = "New Message";

...

$message = <<<EOD

New Form Submitted<br><br>

<b>Name:</b> $name_f $name_l <br>
<b>Phone:</b> $phne <br>
<b>Email:</b> $cont_em <br>

<table border="1">
  <tr><!-- Row 1 -->
     <td></td><!-- Col 1 -->
     <td><span class="table_header">Monday</span></td><!-- Col 2 -->
     <td><span class="table_header">Tuesday</span></td><!-- Col 3 -->
     <td><span class="table_header">Wednesday</span></td><!-- Col 4 -->
     <td><span class="table_header">Thursday</span></td><!-- Col 5 -->
     <td><span class="table_header">Friday</span></td><!-- Col 6 -->
  </tr>
  <tr><!-- Row 2 -->
     <td style="width:140px">9 to 10 AM</td><!-- Col 1 -->
     <td style="width:140px; height:40px">$MON09TO10H</td><!-- Col 2 -->
     <td style="width:140px; height:40px">$TUE09TO10H</td><!-- Col 3 -->
     <td style="width:140px; height:40px">$WED09TO10H</td><!-- Col 4 -->
     <td style="width:140px; height:40px">$THU09TO10H</td><!-- Col 5 -->
     <td style="width:140px; height:40px">$FRI09TO10H</td><!-- Col 6 -->
  </tr>
  <tr><!-- Row 3 -->
     <td>10 to 11 AM</td><!-- Col 1 -->
     <td style="width:140px; height:40px">$MON10TO11H</td><!-- Col 2 -->
     <td style="width:140px; height:40px">$TUE10TO11H</td><!-- Col 3 -->
     <td style="width:140px; height:40px">$WED10TO11H</td><!-- Col 4 -->
     <td style="width:140px; height:40px">$THU10TO11H</td><!-- Col 5 -->
     <td style="width:140px; height:40px">$FRI10TO11H</td><!-- Col 6 -->
  </tr>

 ...

</table>
EOD;

// Send the mail
if (isset($_POST['send']))
{

  $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;  

    if($sent)  

        echo "Success!"
}
else
{
  echo "Error." 
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

`if $type == "work"{`
`echo '<div style="color:red">Work</div>'; }`

`if $type == "free"{`
`echo '<div style="color:green">Free</div>'; }`

Comment: Hi Bender, thanks for  your response - this makes a lot of sense! Where exactly would I put this code? I've edit my question to include snippets of the php file. Would I put the IF statement where ever the variable is called or as a standalone standalone statement, above or below the table?

Comment: its up to you , better put it stand alone